# how to get value in xml attribute through xslt to variable

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

XML:

```
<sheet>
    <row num="4">
        <cell num="1">Customer CODE</cell>
        <cell num="2">2213213</cell>
    </row>
    <row num="5">
        <cell num="1">header</cell>
        <cell num="4">12312</cell>
    </row>
</sheet>
```

I want to set to variable value `5`. Because in 5th row there is cell[@num='1'] which equals to `header`.

This is just returns `true`

```
<xsl:variable name="header_pos" select="//row/cell[@num='1']='header'"/>
```

But I don't know how to get row num value for that cell.. Could you please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the expression you are looking for:

```
<xsl:variable name="header_pos" select="//row[cell[@num='1']='header']/@num"/>
```

i.e Get the row when the cell, with attribute num = '1', has a value of 'header'

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<table xsl:version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:variable name="header_pos" select="sheet/row/cell/@num" />
<xsl:value-of select="$header_pos" separator=", "/>
</table>
```